# Failed to use Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to use `Room` database but I get this error when building the app:

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

and some error like this:

> error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (java.util.ArrayList<com.example.kotlin.Model.BookmarkModel>).

I use `Room` database with these classes:

**BookmarkEntity:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "bookmark")
class BookmarkEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "TITLE")
    var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "URL")
    var url: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IMAGE")
    var image: String
)
```

**BookmarkDataBase:**

```
@Database(entities = [BookmarkEntity::class], version = 1)
abstract class BookmarkDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun bookmark(): BookmarkDAO

    companion object {
        private var instance: BookmarkDataBase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): BookmarkDataBase {
            if (instance == null)
                instance =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context, BookmarkDataBase::class.java, "bookmark")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries()
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .build()
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

**BookmarkDAO:**

```
@Dao
interface BookmarkDAO {

    @Insert
    fun insertData(bookmarkEntity: BookmarkEntity): Boolean

    @Query("select * from bookmark")
    fun getData(): ArrayList<BookmarkModel>

    @Query("DELETE FROM bookmark WHERE id = :id")
    fun deleteData(id: Int)

    @Delete
    fun deleteData(bookmarkEntity: BookmarkEntity)

}
```

I Add this dependencies for `Room`:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"
```

and add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` top of *build.gradle* file. But that error still occurs. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Room`'s query functions can only return an instance of a class which is annotated by `@Entity`. So `BookmarkDAO.getData()` can not return a list of `BookmarkModel`.

So:

```
@Query("select * from bookmark")
fun getData(): List<BookmarkEntity>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't return arraylist i guess,just remove and use list instead.

```
  @Query("select * from bookmark")
fun getData(): ArrayList<BookmarkModel>
```